# Is arXiv a good path for very young researchers?

Tags: computer-science, paper-submission, arxiv

I am 15 years of age and I have studied Computer Science.

This said, I normally read computer science papers on [**arXiv**](http://www.arxiv.org) (cryptography and security, mainly), and I have noticed that some of the papers published are tutorials, basics of fundamental theories and analysis of the most basics topics or techniques. I still read it in hope of discovering something new.

However, I sometimes end up learning nothing new and so I am starting to think that these authors are just publishing these material for sake of it or to reach some sort of goal.

I would love to publish in peer-reviewed journals but I feel like my age may hold me back from my work getting accepted and my lack of connections with the academia again due to my age.

I have done a lot of research pertaining to the pros and cons of publishing in arXiv, I have noticed far too much negativity about it but since I am far younger than most researchers, would it actually raise my stature by showing my knowledge and interest at a young age and build my future opportunities in Academic grounds or is it more likely to tarnish it?

If it may tarnish opportunities, could you specify on how I could avoid this?

Comment: arXiv isn't a journal, it's a preprint repository.  Articles that appear there don't necessarily have to contain original research.  People can upload anything they've written, as long as it has some scientific relevance.  As you say, some people choose to upload tutorials, surveys of previous work, and such.  These may be helpful to some readers but generally do not contribute to the author's academic career.

Comment: I think most people would say putting papers/notes on the arXiv is _posting_ not _publishing_.  For non-research notes (at least in math), I would say something is appropriate for the arXiv if you think it will be of use to researchers.  If it's just material that can be found in a textbook, it's probably not appropriate.  One thing many students do is make a scientific blog, where they write up introductions or surveys to various topics.  Without knowing more about your situation, I think that may be a good thing to try first.

Comment: A good path **to what**?

Comment: Keep in mind that not all arXiv papers are good.  Some are brilliant, many are good but not brilliant, some are mediocre, and some are worthless garbage.  So you shouldn't use unknown papers on the arXiv to calibrate your standards of quality.  Instead of spending time reading more or less random papers on the arXiv, I'd try to seek out particularly good papers and learn from them.  (Seek out the famous papers lots of researchers talk about.  The more you read, the better a feeling you'll get for this, but citations and prizes can be an initial clue.)

Comment: If you reach the point where you can write papers as good as the excellent papers you are reading, you should certainly do so.  In the meantime, learning from the masters will be more productive than reading at random.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician Thanks for your feedback! I suggest you add this as an answer. It is very good, thanks.

Comment: You are concerned that your age may hold you back in publishing.  Some journals and conferences do a double-blind review, which may ensure that you are not discriminated against, due to your age.

Answer (score 2):

Reading just arXiv or even some top journal is not likely to be very helpful.

It used to be that subscribing to a journal (or ten) was the best way to keep up.

But the subscription model is dead, few academics subscribe to journals, few publisher retain print as their primary mode of distribution, and open access publications tend to get 5 or 6 times as many citations as papers that require purchase or subscription.  I presume you read arXiv primarily because it is free.

I presume you are still at high school but finding that not sufficiently challenging.
I presume you have read what you school library has to offer, and need to go beyond.
I presume you have looked at what's available from your local community/university.

Been there done that... I spent my high school years doing my own physics and chemistry experiments, extracting my own reagents and building my own equipment, building electronic devices and computers, programming unbeatable AI games/programs, programs to solve problems in mathematics, joining maths clubs and winning prizes in competitions, making use of university programs designed to encourage budding scientists and mathematicians... exploring my interests in the broadest possible way!

Contact the local university and talk to people there. E.g. I'm happy to take on high school students, and indeed at Flinders University we have the Australian Science and Mathematics School (years 10-12 only) on campus to facilitate just this encouragement of gifted students - but students need to be reasonably local.  Even without a formal program or relationship, academics are happy to talk to high school students, and I've run courses and competitions for high school students, given work experience opportunities and summer scholarships (not exactly restricted to local, but focussed in the state and the surrounding regions that the university draws from).  Sometimes I've just responded to high school kids contacting me out the blue, by working out a program for them. My university actually has a bit of a history of this, with Terry Tao being the most famous example.

What kind of program would I recommend for someone like you... I'd start out by recommending some of the classic papers, introducing you to the originators of the seminal ideas of the field, making sure you had the basics first hand - not via the Chinese whispers of arXiv, review papers or textbooks.  Review papers are often written by PhD students as part of the process of organizing their ideas - it gives them a free publication before they done any significant work on their own.  It also gets them lots of citations, and some people have an h-index that is mainly about their ability to write review papers or text books.  But yes, if there was a particularly good review paper or text book, I'd recommend it - unfortunately for my research area there are no good text books I can use, although I do encourage students to dip into some of those that are around - but my research oriented courses would have at least a dozen original sources of information, and perhaps half a dozen texts or reviews. This leads to an idea from Information Retrieval... Hubs and Authorities.

You've probably heard of Brin & Page's PageRank, which became the basis of Google's ranking based on how much pages linked to each other - it is closely related to singular values/vectors, looking at relatedness of pages in a symmetric way.  But an earlier approach (Kleinberger's HITS/CLEVER) developed around the same time distinguished between the source and target of links, distinguishing hubs (sources of lots of links) and authorities (targets of lots of links) - these relate to the left and right eigenvectors.

What you need to find for your field is the hubs and authorities.  A hub might be a review paper, or a website or society that coordinates the research area.  The authorities are the people/papers that developed the seminal ideas and everyone cites.  Always go to the source, cite the earliest and latest works in their developmental path.  Look for the citations of that work (on Google and Google scholar, concentrating on relevant papers with hints like filetype:pdf and/or site:edu.* | site:edu | site:ac.* to get the papers by academics and find where the open access versions are lurking).  A relationship with a university with relevant subscriptions would also allow you free access to IEEE, Springer etc. But all major publishers now allow people to archive preprints or postprints of their papers for free access - and this is what arXiv should be used for where allowed, but sometimes this permission is restricted to authors' own websites, or their employers'.

There are two ways to explore the field - and you can start from a single of interest.  You can try to go deep and specific (citations of and by that paper).  You can also go broad and applied (citations of the citations). Modern citation analysis is closely related to PageRank/HITS/CLEVER, and your library may have tools to help.

Answer (score 2):

It's great to get involved in these types of things at a young age. Before I say anything else: don't stop - be curious, but don't be curious to impress people. I was exactly like you. But don't let that get in your head. There are literally students in their teens working to cure cancer and have had publications. That proves how smart they are. You need to do the same.

Actually I have indeed seen many people get "pre-print" published and not get it published anywhere else.

If you want to get published, Look for a journal/conference with a double-blind reviewer process (that way they won't know that you are from high school). Next, do **a lot** of readings in the area you wish to publish in. You need to understand the lingo of the field immensely before publishing in it (not just ten or a hundred; honestly, I would spend countless days reading papers - you **MUST** absorb everything in the field).

This is coming from a guy who worked as a research assistant while in high school. In fact, I know several friends who were in high school when they got their first publication; one was at an IEEE conference.

Another route, would be to look out for the Intel Science Fair or the Google Science Fair to show case your work. I'd highly recommend looking into those.

As one of the other posters said, professors usually love talking to bright students - But, they are looking for bright, humble students (not people who will waste their time) - So be careful!

Answer (score 1):

##### No, it definitely isn't --- use the peer-review system, at least until you get good

You are correct to note that one of the frustrating aspects of open-access repositories like ArXiv is that they include many low-quality submissions, which makes it harder to find the good papers.  Consequently, the absolute *last thing* that academia needs is to have these repositories become even more clogged up with vanity papers written by fifteen year-olds.  Sorry if that sounds a bit harsh, but it is the reality of what you are proposing.

Since you are very young, a much better pathway is to try to master your field through coursework, self-study, etc., and then submit to peer-reviewed journals once you are ready to do so.  Ordinarily, students pursuing an academic path go through an undergraduate and graduate education, and they are usually in their mid-twenties or older when they are in grad-school and first start to publish papers.  There are many drawbacks on the traditional peer-reviewed academic journal system, but the great advantage is that these journals provide you with peer-review and a filtering mechanism.  This is especially useful for novice researchers, to help them develop up to a level where their papers are worth publishing.

You are not going to raise your academic stature in any serious way merely by demonstrating your *interest* in a field.  In terms of trying to demonstrate your knowledge, be careful what you wish for --- given your age, it is likely that your level of knowledge is extremely low compared to older researchers, so any work you publish is likely to exhibit your *lack of knowledge*.

> I would love to publish in peer-reviewed journals but I feel like my age may hold me back from my work getting accepted and my lack of connections with the academia again due to my age.

Anyone can submit a paper to a peer-reviewed academic journal --- just hop onto their submission website and follow the submission procedure.  Most peer-reviewed journals use a blinded review system where the reviewers have no information on the identity of the author and no idea what "connections" they do or don't have.  Even in the ones that don't use blinded review, the paper will usually only contain your name and maybe your institution, but not your age.  So, unless there are some cues to infer your age from your writing, the referees reviewing your papers will have no idea whether you are 15 or 80.

The only thing that will hold you back from publishing in peer-reviewed journals is limitation on your ability to write a scholarly paper at the required standard.  Some recreational/college journals publish simple papers and have had some young authors in their teens, often co-authors working with an older established researcher (see e.g., the [*College Mathematics Journal*](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/the-college-mathematics-journal)).  Some conferences and their conference proceedings are also places where a very young researcher might be able to meet the requisite standard for publication.

Comment: Yes, perhaps the best feature of the peer-review system is the helpful (hopefully! but not dependably!) feedback it gives to novices. Certainly stylistic feedback, though, yes, to some degree, that's just about conformity. But, also, genuine content feedback. (As one moves forward, this system become less reliable and worthwhile to engage-with, but it is generally positive at the beginning.)